# Using Angular CLI to reverse proxy to a service in API Gateway/lambda

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to reverse proxy Angular using the `proxy.conf.json` to a lambda behind API gateway.

```
{
    "/api/profile/*": {
        "target": "http://asdasdfsdf.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": false,
        "headers": {
            "host":"asdasdfsdf.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api/profile": "/dev/profile"
        }
    },
}
```

I think there is an issue with the `host` header.

If I hit this now, I get unauthorized

[image]

However when I add the host header explicitly in postman, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the `bypass` option.

To use it we have to change the `proxy.conf.json` to `proxy.conf.js`.
Check that all the references to `proxy.conf.json` now point to `proxy.conf.js` ( maybe you have it in `angular.json` , in `options.proxyConfig` or in the `package.json`).

After this we add the code to add the bypass option(in `proxy.conf.js` and it would end looking something like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG =
{
    "/api/profile/*": {
        target: "http://asdasdfsdf.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
        secure: false,
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: false,
        bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            req.headers["host"] = "asdasdfsdf.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com";
        },
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/api/profile": "/dev/profile"
        }
    },
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score 0):

`"target": "http://asdasdfsdf.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"` was doing a redirect to `https:// ...`. The proxy respected the redirect but it did not forward the headers in the config.

The solution was to use the `https` directly.